# DriveApp makecopy returns an error I can't understand

Tags: google-apps-script

[image: driveApp error]

[image: my code]

I can't understand why DriveApp returns that error. In the code image I show that all the data and the syntax are correct, as far I know. All the file and folder id showed in the debug window are 100% correct and verified.
Please, someone can help me?

Comment: Please learn how to post and [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Evidentyly easiminator[i][3] is not of type [Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change `easiminator[i][3]` with `DriveApp.getFolderById(easiminator[i][3])`

Comment: @Cooper Yes it is, is a folder and has just been created in the same function with .createfolder().

Comment: your trick was right, now it works. Can you explain me what happened?

Comment: From the debugger panel I assume the `easiminator[i][3]` is a string (and the string looks like ID). But `makeCopy()` method takes a Folder object as a second argument. `DriveApp.getFolderById()` takes ID and returns the Folder.